# How to transform array object into array string

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a result console like this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

i want to result like this

```
[{value: '1', text: 'one'}, {value: '2', text: 'two'}]
```

[this is full of code](https://jsfiddle.net/oyocxdz4/)

Comment: \*What have you tried?

Comment: [please see this code](https://jsfiddle.net/oyocxdz4/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($nested_object), true);
```

OR just typecast it:

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do want to do it through loop i think you can use this

```
$array = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach(Object as $val)
{
   $array[$counter]['value'] = $val->value;
   $array[$counter]['text']  = $val->text; 
   $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.stringify()`

```js
var obj = [{value: '1', text: 'one'}, {value: '2', text: 'two'}]
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```